# how do i show div using dropdown's value

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am new in rails.I have a "drop down" which contains values 1 to 10 in "index page" like:

`<% @offers.each do |f|%>`
`<%= f.select :Conditions.......%>`

In "show page" i have `many div` with visibility is equal to false.So, i want to show div by the selected value.

For example if i `select 5` and pressing the submit button then i want to show only `5 div`.
Is there any other way to get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using [change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/) of your select, as example:

```
$('#offers_conditions').change(function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  $('.class-for-all-divs').hide();
  $('#' + val).show();
});
```